# Назад на дерикторию PHP

Tags: php

Вот я нахожусь в папке /admin/, файл index.php. В нем определяю контстанту:

```
define('FILE', dirname(__DIR__));
```

Теперь мне нужно вернуться назад и открыть другую дерикторию. Я определяю еще константу, пытаюсь вернуться назад и открыть дерикторию core/, но не получается:

```
define('FILE', dirname(__DIR__));
define('ROOT', dirname(FILE));
require(ROOT.'/core/functions.php');
```

> Warning: require(./core/functions.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Z:homeacmswwwadminindex.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required './core/functions.php' (include_path='.;/usr/local/php5/PEAR') in Z:homeacmswwwadminindex.php on line 6

Подскажите пожалуйста, а то я новичок в PHP

Comment: Z:homeacmswwwadminindex.php - опечатка или именно так?

Comment: Нет, это тут слэши куда то подевались. Так все нормально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы за пределы www выходите.
Видимо, вы хотели сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
define('FILE', dirname(__FILE__));
define('ROOT', dirname(FILE));
require(ROOT.'/core/functions.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы знаете, где находитесь, почему бы просто не подгрузить все, используя относительный путь:

```
require('../core/functions.php');
```

Comment: почему у меня никогда не работают эти две точки и слеш, что вернутся на директорию? Он просто дописывает это в путь.
К примеру надо выйти из папки public и зайти в папку php
require "../php/something_file.php";
то генирируется вот такая дичь
/public/../php/something_file.php;
Я думаю может разница в круглых скобках есть?